# Meaning of the phrase "Line $Y$ spanned by $\vec x$" and "Plane $D$ spanned by $\vec x$, $\vec y$, and $\vec z$"

Tags: linear-algebra

If I say the Line $Y$ spanned by $\vec x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ = $\begin{bmatrix}3 \\2\end{bmatrix}$, then do I mean that $\vec x$ is parallel or perpendicular to Line $Y$?

If I say the Plane $D$ spanned by $\vec x$  = $\begin{bmatrix}a \\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$, $\vec y$ = $\begin{bmatrix}d \\e\\f\end{bmatrix}$, and $\vec z$ = $\begin{bmatrix}g \\h\\i\end{bmatrix}$  then do I mean that $\vec x$, $\vec y$, and $\vec z$  are parallel or perpendicular to Plane $D$?

Comment: The second phrase has no meaning because makes no sense: a plane cannot be spanned by a single vector.  A plane could be spanned by two vectors, and a plane could be specified in *other* ways by a single vector, but it certainly could not be spanned by one.

Comment: The line is all real multiples of the vector and forms a vector space (if you add two points on the line you get another point on the line). This is what you mean by "spanned". A plane cannot be spanned by a single vector but needs linear combinations of two non-colinear vectors. The two spanning vectors are parallel to the plane.

Comment: @ErickWong See edit; could a plane be spanned by three vectors? In the first phrase, is $\vec x$ parallel to Line Y?

Comment: It could, but normally it would not: take (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) and (0, 0, 1) (the $x$-axis, $y$-axis and $z$-axis), which generate the entire $\mathbb{R}^3$ space

Comment: More likely in the second case they're referring to the plane passing through the three *points*  $\vec x$, $\vec y$, $\vec z$. This is the *affine* plane spanned by the three vectors, as opposed to the linear subspace spanned by three vectors.

Answer (score 1):

*First question*

The vector $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$ is the vector that starts at the origin $\big($in $\mathbb{R}^2$, this is the point $(0, 0)$ $\big)$ and ends at the point $(a, b)$. Therefore, we identify a vector with its ending point.

The line **spanned** by $\vec x = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ is formed by the endpoints of the vectors $\lambda \vec x, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ (the real multiples of $\vec x$). For example, the point $(3\sqrt{2}, 2\sqrt{2})$ is in the line because it is the endpoint of $\sqrt{2} \vec x$. Just drawing a few of these endpoints one can see that $\vec x$ is parallel (actually coincides on) the line spanned by $\vec x$ itself.

*Second question*

Two vectors $v_1, v_2$ **span** (or *generate*) a plane consisting of points of the form $\lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2$. (An exception to this is when $v_1$ and $v_2$ lie on the same line, when $v_2$ can be written as $\lambda' v_1$).

In general, $n$ possibly (but not necessarily) different vectors $v_1, \dots, v_n$ generate a set consisting of points of the form $\lambda_1 v_1+ \dots+ \lambda_nv_n$ (the so-called *linear combinations*) with $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Back to the question, a third vector $v_3$ may not lie on the plane spanned by $v_1, v_2$ (see the $x, y, z$-axis example in the comments of the question). If $v_3$ does lie on the plane, that means for some $\mu_1, mu_2$ it holds that $v_3=\mu_1v_1+\mu_2v_2$. Then what is spanned by $v_1, v_2$ and $v_3$ is of the form
$$\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\lambda_3v_3 = \lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\lambda_3(\mu_1v_1+\mu_2v_2)$$
which is in what is spanned by only $v_1,v_2$ (now you can read about linear dependency)